# If the condition number of a matrix $A$ under the $l_2$-norm equals $1$, prove that $A^T A$ = $aI$ where $a$ is a nonzero scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got to the point where I've figured out that the maximum and minimum eigenvalue are equal, therefore we can say that $A^T A$ has one eigenvalue, say $a$. However then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write the eigendecomposition of $A^\top\! A$, i.e. $A^\top\! A = P\, a I\, P^{-1} = a I$ where $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors

Comment: Alright that was all I needed to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm back! Could you elaborate on why $A^T A$ is diagonizable? I'm not very strong in linear algebra so I'm not sure if this is a trivial property or not.

Comment: Because $A^T A$ is symmetric. This is easy to show: $(A^T A)^T = A^T (A^T)^T = A^T A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition number of a matrix is given by

$$ \kappa(A) = \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}} \tag{1}$$

under the $2$ norm. Now note that

consider that the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix $Q$ are either $1$ or $-1$ so we get

$$ \kappa(Q) =  \frac{1}{1} =1  \tag{2}$$

Then you so note that

$$ Q^{T}Q = QQ^{T} = I \tag{3} $$

if we multiply by a scalar we have

$$ a \cdot Q^{T}Q = a \cdot QQ^{T} = a \cdot I \tag{4} $$

This would mean the eigenvalues are equal to $aI$

Alternatively

$$ A^{T}A  = Ia \tag{5} $$
$$ (U \Sigma V^{T} )^{T}(U \Sigma V^{T}) \tag{6} $$
$$ V \Sigma^{T} U^{T} U \Sigma V^{T} \tag{7} $$

we know 
$$ UU^{T} = U^{T}U = I  $$

$$ V \Sigma^{T} \Sigma V^{T} \tag{8} $$

$$ \Sigma^{T} \Sigma  = \Lambda $$
$$ V \Lambda V^{T}  = aI \tag{9} $$
$$ \implies \Lambda   = aI \tag{10} $$

Comment: But this is proving it the other way around, right? In my case we start off with the given that the condition number is 1 and we have to prove the other statement.

Comment: It is. The condition number of an orthogonal  matrix is 1 though. I can fix it.